API cannot retrieve mysql-mariadb data from backend express js for react ts
I use React ts as frontend, mariadb as database, express js as backend and axios to make API. I define shared type of data contact and lead in the root project to provide backend and frontend, so they can sharing data.
But the data nothing displayed in component table. The UI also get blank and in console it says: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Even actually the API not receive the data from the backend. i checked api from postman, but nothing json as expected except html code.

So for more clear, Below I show the configuration that I tried to make.
This is my shared contact data
export enum Status {
    ENTRY = 'masuk',
    FOLLOW_UP = 'follow up',
    IDLE = 'menganggur',
    FAIL = 'gagal',
    DEAL = 'deal'
  }
  
  export interface Contact {
    contact_id: number;
    entry_date: Date;
    person: string;
    institution: string;
    position: string;
    email_address: string;
    phone: string;
    phone2: string;
    socmed_link: string;
    socmed_link2: string;
    status: Status;
    descriptions: string;
  }
 

This is my Contact model in the backend
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from './index';
import { Contact as ContactType, Status } from '../../../shared/types/Contact';

export class Contact extends Model<ContactType> implements ContactType {
  public contact_id!: number;
  public entry_date!: Date;
  public person!: string;
  public institution!: string;
  public position!: string;
  public email_address!: string;
  public phone!: string;
  public phone2!: string;
  public socmed_link!: string;
  public socmed_link2!: string;
  public status!: Status;
  public descriptions!: string;
  static associate: (models: any) => void;
}

Contact.init(
  {
    contact_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    entry_date: DataTypes.DATE,
    person: DataTypes.STRING,
    institution: DataTypes.STRING,
    position: DataTypes.STRING,
    email_address: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone2: DataTypes.STRING,
    socmed_link: DataTypes.STRING,
    socmed_link2: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM(...Object.values(Status)),
      defaultValue: Status.ENTRY,
    },
    descriptions: DataTypes.TEXT,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'contacts',
  }
);

Contact.associate = (models: any) => {
  Contact.hasMany(models.Lead, { foreignKey: 'person', sourceKey: 'person' });
  Contact.hasMany(models.Lead, { foreignKey: 'institution', sourceKey: 'institution' });
  Contact.hasMany(models.Lead, { foreignKey: 'email_address', sourceKey: 'email_address' });
  Contact.hasMany(models.Lead, { foreignKey: 'active_phone', sourceKey: 'phone' });
};

export default Contact; // Export instansi model Contact

This is my index.ts at models folder in the backend (ignore db configuration)
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import path from 'path';
import { Contact } from './Contact';
import { Lead } from './Lead';

const modelsPath = path.join(__dirname, '.');

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: 'xxx',
  dialect: 'mariadb',
  username: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx',
  models: [modelsPath], // Daftar model
});

export { Contact, Lead };

This is my dashboardController in backend (i have leads data and contacts data. i want both retrieved in one endpoint in dashboard)
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import Contact from '../models/Contact';
import Lead from '../models/Lead';

export const getDashboardData = async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const contacts = await Contact.findAll();
    const leads = await Lead.findAll();
    
    res.json({ contacts, leads });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching dashboard data', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
};

This is for the route in backend
import { Router } from 'express';
import { Contact } from '../models/Contact';
import { Lead } from '../models/Lead';

const router = Router();

router.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const contacts = await Contact.findAll();
    const leads = await Lead.findAll();
    res.json({ contacts, leads });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

export default router;

And this is index.ts for server entry point in the src folder of backend
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { sequelize } from './models';
import contactRoutes from './routes/contactRoutes';
import leadRoutes from './routes/leadRoutes';
import dashboardRoutes from './routes/dashboardRoutes';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Menggunakan rute
app.use('/api', dashboardRoutes); // Pastikan menggunakan prefix /api untuk rute API
app.use('/contacts', contactRoutes);
app.use('/leads', leadRoutes);

// Menghubungkan ke database dan memulai server
sequelize.sync({ alter: true }).then(() => {
  console.log('Database & tables created!');
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server berjalan di http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});

This is the API file (api.ts) in frontend
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5173/api';

export const getDashboardData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/dashboard`);
    return response.data || [];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching dashboard data', error);
    return { contacts: [], leads: [] };
  }
};

export const getContacts = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/contacts`);
    return response.data || [];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching contacts', error);
    return [];
  }
};

export const getLeads = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/leads`);
    return response.data || [];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching leads', error);
    return [];
  }
};

My App.tsx in frontend
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Navigate, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainLayout from './MainLayout';
import React from 'react';


const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<MainLayout/>} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App

My MainLayout.tsx in frontend
import React from "react";
import { Box, Container, CssBaseline, GlobalStyles, Grid, Paper, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import ContactTable from "./components/ContactTable";
import ContactMain from "./components/ContactMain";
import MyAppBar from "./components/MyAppBar";
import darkTheme from "./darkTheme";

const MainLayout: React.FC = () => {
    return (
    <>
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <GlobalStyles styles={{ body: { backgroundColor: darkTheme.palette.background.default } }} />
      <MyAppBar/>
      <Box sx={{ height: '100vh', flexGrow: 1, padding: 0, '@media(max-width:768px)': {
          paddingX: 1,
        }}}>
        <Container sx={{ 
          height: '100vh',
          marginY: '8%',
          padding: 0,
          marginX: 0,
          '@media(max-width: 1023.98px)': {
              marginY: '5rem',
          },
          '@media(min-width: 1024px)': {
              marginY: '6rem',
          },
          '@media(min-width: 1200px)': {
              maxWidth: '100vw',
            },
          }}>
          <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 3 }} sx={{ height: '100%' }} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
            <Grid item xs={4} sm={2} md={2} sx={{ height: '75%' }}>
              <Paper sx={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#444' }}></Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4} sm={6} md={7} sx={{ height: '75%' }}>
              <ContactMain/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4} sm={8} md={3} sx={{ height: '75%' }}>
              <Paper sx={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#444' }} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4} sm={2} md={9} sx={{ height: '75%' }}>
              <Paper sx={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#444' }}>
                {/* <ContactTable/> */}
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4} sm={6} md={3} sx={{ height: '75%' }}>
              <Paper sx={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#444' }} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </>
    )
}

export default MainLayout

My ContactMain.tsx in frontend
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Paper } from "@mui/material";
import ContactHeader from "./ContactHeader";
import ContactUtilities from "./ContactUtilities";
import ContactTable from './ContactTable';
  
const ContactMain: React.FC = () => {

    return (
        <Paper sx={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#444' , p: 1 }}>
            <ContactHeader/>
            <ContactUtilities/>
            <ContactTable/>
        </Paper>
    )
}

export default ContactMain

And this is my ContactTable.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { getDashboardData, getContacts, getLeads } from '../services/api';
import { Contact } from '../../shared/types/Contact';
import { Lead } from '../../shared/types/Lead';  

const ContactTable: React.FC = () => {

    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState<Contact[]>([]);
    const [leads, setLeads] = useState<Lead[]>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          setError(null);
          try {
            const { contacts, leads } = await getDashboardData();
            console.log('Contacts Data:', contacts);
            console.log('Leads Data:', leads);
            setContacts(contacts);
            setLeads(leads);
          } catch (err) {
            setError('Failed to fetch data');
          } finally {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    if (error) {
    return <p>{error}</p>;
    }
  
    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <h1>Contacts</h1>
            <ul>
                {contacts.map(contact => (
                    <li key={contact.contact_id}>{contact.person}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>

            <h1>Leads</h1>
            <ul>
                {leads.map(lead => (
                    <li key={lead.lead_id}>{lead.lead_title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    )
}

export default ContactTable

I try connect my database to my backend, but not yet success, and surely i try to connect backend to frontend, for the first to retrieve data, it didn't work. data should be received to API so they can showed up in component Table.
